# GitLab CI/runner with embedded testing

Tags: automated-tests, gitlab, integration-testing, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We're writing software for an embedded platform for which we also need automated on-device testing.

When a push/tagging is made to the repository a GitLab pipeline is started. The first step is to build the software.

The next step is to execute a custom written Python script (doing the testing) on a machine running locally in our office. This machine is physically connected to the embedded device via USB, hence the testing-part of the CI pipeline needs to be executes on this machine exclusively. The Python script needs to be executes multiple times with different parameters, but may (and should) run concurrently if possible.

Is this setup possible with GitLab runners, and if so, how do I configure it to only run this exact part of the pipeline locally?

Thanks in advance